# Eclipse Generate Java Doc for certain methods only

Tags: java, eclipse, javadoc

Right now when I generate Java Doc, I get bunch of errors. I was wondering if it is possible to generate Java Doc for certain methods. Say I am making a class to be used by others. I would like them to be able to see the Java Docs for my class. I get the following errors:

```
package org.json does not exist
import org.json.JSONException;
```

But JSON java doc are irrelevant. All I need them to be able to see are docs for the methods that I wrote in a class XYZ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible, but is not common. Native Javadoc does not support this, I think:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/faq/index.html#exclude

But you might have some luck with the [Exclude Doclet](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/excludedoclet/index.jsp).

Comment: I haven't used this in particular, but the documentation [here](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/excludedoclet/docs/excludedoclet.html) is probably enough to get you going. One thing you may try, as noted there, is that you can already exclude packages (just not specific classes) using the [-exclude option](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#exclude). Presumably, you could "-exclude" org.json to keep it from being selected at all. If that's enough, then you might not need the doclet at all.

Comment: "Works with JDK 1.4.x and 5.x. " From the website. Am I to assume this does not work for Java 6?